# How do I install QuickTime 10.1 on Snow Leopard?

Tags: quicktime

I haven't upgraded to Lion yet and was thinking of keeping this Mac running Snow Leopard and buy a new Mac with Lion.

So I hope to install the newest QuickTime 10.1 on the current Mac running Snow Leopard.  It already has QuickTime 10.0 (128) so it can record the screen as `.mov`, but it can't select a region on the screen to do the recording like on a Lion Mac in the Apple Store (which has QuickTime 10.1).  (so QuickTime 10.0 must record the full screen, it seems, and the duo core CPU is not powerful enough).

But I don't see any upgrade link inside QuickTime's about or help, and I don't see it on Apple's website (only QuickTime 7 is available).  Is it possible to upgrade to QuickTime 10.1 on Snow Leopard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Snow Leopard already comes with [QuickTime X](http://gigaom.com/apple/snow-leopard-in-depth-quicktime-x/). And as for trying to port Lion's version to Snow Leopard, that can't be done. QuickTime is a core component and like any integral piece of software, requires many libraries and APIs only available on Lion. It's not as simple as trying to copy over the contents of an .app bundle.

Comment: I thought QuickTime is a standalone app... kind of like QuickTime on Windows.  Is there a way to make the Mac dual boot either Snow Leopard or Lion then?   (bootcamp can do that?)

Comment: Nope. QT is an incredibly integral part of the OS. Bootcamp is for Windows only. Dual booting OS X only requires that you install them on separate partitions. Then during boot, hold the ALT key to select which you'd like to load.

Comment: aha... i am wondering if I buy another computer with Lion, whether I should spend another $30 and the time to make the current computer dual boot, just to make QT 10.1 work... I am wondering too for QT 10.0 to record a smaller region, maybe one way is to set the screen resolution to a lower one